# how to calculate the value like css3 calc function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanted to perform the calculation with the ternary operator in my javascript something like below:

```
object > (50% - 10px) ? doThis : doThat
```

here the (50% - 10px) won't work but like (50 -10) would work. So how do I calculate the values with percentage and pixels?

Comment: The % are calculated according to parent element dimensions. If you need 50%, get 50% off the parent's corresponding dimension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First convert 50% to a number of pixels. For example

```
var halfWidth = .5 * parent.offsetWidth;
```

Then you can compare like this:

```
 object > halfWidth - 10 ? doThis :doThat
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use math operations with strings. You should provide all elements to **numbers**.

If 50% is width of the window, you need to get the value of that 50%, something like:

`window.width * 50/100`

And the second thing, you should remove 'px' from second parameter. Use RegExp.

Hope it would be helpful.